# Game Center multiplayer over 3G/WWAN - getLocalConnectionData timed out

Tags: iphone, networking, gamekit, 3g-network

I have a multiplayer game that uses GameCenter for networking. Network games over wifi using GKMatch work perfectly, but over 3G they never connect. My

```
-[GKMatchmaker findMatchForRequest:
withCompletionHandler:]
```

completion handler block is invoked with an error code 503, which isn't a `GKErrorDomainCode` according to that header. Instead it appears to be an HTTP error code.

Here's my code:

```
//GKLocalPlayer is already authenticated at this point
    _matchRequest = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [_matchRequest setMinPlayers: 2];
    [_matchRequest setMaxPlayers: 2];
    GKMatchmaker *matchmaker = [GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker];
    [matchmaker findMatchForRequest: _matchRequest
              withCompletionHandler:
     ^(GKMatch *match, NSError *error) {
         if (error)
         {
             if ([error code] != GKErrorCancelled)
             {
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: 
                          NSLocalizedString(@"Can't find match.", @"Alert title for when automatching failed") 
                          message: [error localizedDescription] 
                          delegate: nil 
                          cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"Button text for OK button") 
                          otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease] show];
                 });
             }
             else
             {
                    NSLog(@"Canceled :(");
             }
         }
         else
         { 
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 // do some main-thread stuff specific to my app
                 _match = [match retain];
                 [_match setDelegate: self];
             });
         }
     } ];
}
```

`SNJGKLocalPlayerManager` just logs the player into GameCenter. Typical output from this would be a `UIAlertView` saying "The operation could not be completed. `getLocalConnectionData` timed out" from the line in the first dispatch_async block. If I use `NSLog` to output the error code, it's 503.

If you've gotten `GameCenter` multiplayer to work over 3G and don't want to pore over my code, feel free to share your working code and I'll try to find where mine goes wrong! Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps not. At first it appeared that this fixed the problem, but no longer. I'm no longer convinced that I had turned Wifi off while testing this change, because I'm not unable to reproduce the desired behavior.

Comment: have you managed to find a solution?